# OpenGL - Render same size regardless of screen size / ratio

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm rendering a 2D flat tiled surface in OpenGL (Android), I'm setting up the viewport using the following:

```
float ratio = (float) width / height;
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, MIN_ZOOM + 1.0f);
```

In landscape mode this looks great but if I switch to portrait everything is rendered much larger. I've been reading about the frustum and transforms and scales but I'm not sure exactly which would apply here.

It is my understanding that the frustum is correct as the extents should be -ratio - ratio and 1 - 1.

Is that correct? If so, should I use scale or transform to make the tiles and other elements render at the same physical size regardless of orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for example, say your screen is 1200 x 800. In landscape mode you will have:

```
ratio = 1.5
frustrum (left, right, bottom, top) = -1.5, 1.5, -1, 1
```

So your frustrum is 3 units wide, 2 units high. In portrait:

```
ratio = 0.667
frustrum (left, right, bottom, top) = -0.667, 0.667, -1, 1
```

...it is now 1.333 units wide and 2 units high. So although the frustrum is the same ratio between shortest side and longest side, it is smaller in scale in portrait hence the rendering appears closer and larger. What you want for portrait is:

```
frustrum = -1, 1, -1.5, 1.5
```

...so that, as for landscape, the shortest screen dimension will be 2 units and the longest 3. Check if the ratio is greater than 1 (to determine orientation) and set the frustrum accordingly:

```
if (ratio >= 1.0f)
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, MIN_ZOOM + 1.0f); //Landscape
else
    gl.glFrustumf(-1, 1, -1/ratio, 1/ratio, 1, MIN_ZOOM + 1.0f); //Portrait
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! That has ended a day of huge frustration!